# How to add an independent button to upload selected files on bootstrap file input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-file-input

Bootstrap file input provides default uploading button

[image]

But I want an independent button to upload the selected files
[image]

Any idea how I can fix it without getting too complicated?